# Add Ubuntu to Arch linux Dual boot, Keeping Syslinux, without GRUB

Tags: ubuntu, arch-linux, partition, dual-boot, syslinux

#### Situation

I have Arch Linux installed on `/dev/sda1` (15GB/ext4). `/` and `/boot` are both on `/dev/sda1` and `/home` is on `/dev/sda2` (100GB/ext4). I made a 15GB/ext4 `/dev/sda3` partition for Ubuntu. I installed Syslinux as the bootloader.

#### Problem

How do I dual-boot-install Ubuntu onto `/dev/sda3` without installing GRUB, without ruining my Syslinx bootloader and how do I share the home partition `/dev/sda2` between the two OS's?

---

#### Update

I learned how to boot into Ubuntu correctly and found out that chainloading is unnecessary.

Here's what I did:

1. Wiped Ubuntu off `/dev/sda3` and reinstalled it in the same place.
2. Made a new directory on `/dev/sda1` named `/boot/ubuntu`,
3. Copied all of `/boot` from `/dev/sda3` to the new directory in step 1 (because the the kernel and initrd files for Ubuntu were there),
4. Edited `/boot/syslinux/syslinux.cfg` from `/dev/sda1`. See below for the entry:

   ```
   LABEL Ubuntu
        MENU LABEL Ubuntu
        LINUX ../ubuntu/vmlinuz-3.5.0-23-generic
        APPEND root=/dev/sda3 ro
        INITRD ../ubuntu/initrd.img-3.5.0-23-generic
   ```

If I were smart, I would probably have a dedicated boot partition. Oh well, it wasn't part of the original question so I'll just worry about that later.

However, I was hoping that Ubuntu would use `/dev/sda2` as the shared home partition and it didn't :(

**Anybody know how to fix the `/home/user` folder so it's on `/dev/sda2`?**

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Syslinux#Chainloading_other_Linux_systems

Comment: Thanks, JasonWRyan. That guide sounds like its for directions if I installed Ubuntu on `/dev/sda3` already, which I haven't. Am I supposed to setup syslinux and extlinux this way before I install Ubuntu on `/dev/sda3`? I'm at the Ubuntu install screen and its asking for me to choose the "Device for boot loader installation." Since I've never installed Ubuntu like this before, I thought it might be a mistake to install another boot loader (GRUB I assume) since I already have one (syslinux). But I don't have the choice not to install a boot loader.

Comment: Skip that step and finish the Ubuntu install, and then boot into Arch and configure syslinux to chainload Ubuntu.

Comment: I don't think I can skip this step. At this point the installer seems to give me only two choices: 1) Erase everything and install Ubuntu as the only OS, or 2) Install Ubuntu all on a partition of my choice, including the boot loader all on one partition.

Comment: I guess I'll just go for it and cross my fingers. I'll let you know what happens...

Comment: You need the alternate install disk to skip grub, [apparently...](http://askubuntu.com/questions/132116/installing-ubuntu-12-04-without-installing-grub)

Comment: Ok, so, I installed Ubuntu on `/dev/sda3` (ext4). Then I looked at the link in the first comment above, noticing that extlinux is for ext2 or ext3 filesystems (in its man page). And, also, I noticed that, after mounting `/dev/sda3` to /mnt, there is no `/mnt/boot/syslinux` file or directory. At least my biggest fear hasen't come true - that I'd have to redo my Arch installation. Should I fix what I have or try to redo Ubuntu?

Comment: You have to create that directory... Extlinux works fine on ext4 filesystems.

Comment: I made a syslinux directory in `/boot` of `/dev/sda3`, followed the instructions under the "Chainloading Other Linux Systems" from the link in the first comment, restarted, and didn't see any Ubuntu. I'll have to continue this tomorrow. Thanks for all your help so far.

Comment: Sorry I took so long to return. Life got in the way. I have tried some new things and updated the original question above.

Comment: Any reason you have to keep Syslinux? Install Grub2 might just make your life a lot easier.

Comment: @number5, I like syslinux 'cause its not associated with Ubuntu the way GRUB is. Ubuntu is on its last straw with me. I'm only using it for social media and marketing purposes now. I'm trying to learn as much as possible about Arch Linux. Oh well, reluctantly I'll try the chainloading technique with syslinux and GRUB2 I guess. I'd much rather do things the right way than the easy way but I'll let you know how this goes. :(

Comment: @Rhyknowscerious that make sense. Even though GRUB is not associated with Ubuntu, actually most Linux distros use GRUB, included Arch Linux

Answer (score -1):

Install Ubuntu and add `/dev/sda2` to your `fstab` as `/home2` any files will be accessible.